# Sentence participle II role

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I have a sentence and I want to understand word "preoccupied" role in it.

> I became preoccupied with work.

My analysis:
Direct word order.
I - subject, personal pronoun.
became - predicate, irregular verb.
preoccupied - definition, participle II.
with - conjunction, preposition.
work - circumstance, noun.

Is this analyse correct? What's wrong? Please, help to write correct word order scheme.

Maybe the "preoccupied" is an indirect object and "with work" is a direct object with preposition? 
Or "preoccupied" is the part of predicate?

Comment: The word [**preoccupied**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/preoccupied) is an adjective which qualifies the speaker, and is further described as **preoccupied with work**. Related is [Phrase Question “Be preoccupied with”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355204/phrase-question-be-preoccupied-with).